# Debugging (Eclipse): No time to debug: Browser Times Out with "Internal Server Error"

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, debugging, browser

When I debug my Java app in Eclipse, I need to step through a lot of code. But the time window for doing that is very limited, only about 45 sec. - 1 min., and I can't complete my step-by-step debugging.

The browsers time out very fast, as seen below with Google Chrome ("Internal Server Error"). How do I give myself more breathing room to debug properly? Is it a Browser issue?

[image]

Comment: It's a backend timeout I guess, not a browser problem. If it's tomcat you can try [setting](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html) connectionTimeout=-1 for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

1) I had an Apache HTTP server configured which had its own timeout (separate from Tomcat). I bypassed it by running the app on the :8080 port directly, localhost:8080/myapp/ rather than local/myapp/.

2) Generally, as Luis Munoz said above, the `Connector` property in Tomcat's `server.xml` should be as follows, with connectionTimeout=-1.

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="-1" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```